# Repeat select statement like a foreach loop

Tags: sql-server-2008, loops, select

Is there a way to make a SELECT statement repeat itself ?

Take this query :

```
DECLARE @one INT = 1
SELECT @one + @one AS [MATH]
```

The output would be

```
 ------
| MATH |
 ------
|  2   |
 ------
```

What I'm trying to do is repeat this SELECT statement for each different numbers like this

```
 -- PSEUDO CODE

 DECLARE @Numbers NVARCHAR(MAX) = '1,2,3,4'
 FOR EACH INT @number IN @Numbers 
 BEGIN 

   SELECT @number + @number AS [MATH]

 END
```

The output would be :

```
 ------     
| MATH | 
 ------
|  2   |
 ------  
 ------     
| MATH | 
 ------
|  4   |
 ------  
 ------     
| MATH | 
 ------
|  6   |
 ------ 
 ------
| MATH | 
 ------
|  8   |
 ------
```

I know they are not INT at that time but I have a function that splits on the ',' and then convert the varchar to numbers.

I don't know how I could put this in a WHILE loop because I can't find a suitable condition.

Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: Well, the goal isn't to select each number individually, is it? Could you explain what you actually want to do with the results of the function?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Common Table Expressions can recurse.

Here's an example:  http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/07/28/sql-server-simple-example-of-recursive-cte/

Or you could use a while loop, popping the numbers off your string.

```
 declare @sum = 0
 while len(@string) > 0
 begin
      select @sum + convert(int, substring(1,charindex(',',@string),@string)))
      select 'Math: '+ltrim(str(@sum))
      select @string = substring(charindex(',',@string),len(@string),@string)
 end
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
DECLARE @Numbers NVARCHAR(MAX) = '1,2,3,4'
DECLARE @num int=0
WHILE CHARINDEX(',',@Numbers) > 0
BEGIN 
SET @num=convert(int,LEFT(@Numbers,1))
SET @Numbers=STUFF(REPLACE(@Numbers,LEFT(@Numbers,1),''),1,1,'')
SELECT @num + @num AS [MATH]
END
select convert(int,@Numbers)+convert(int,@Numbers)
```